# Add dynamic text to ToolTip in Html ActionLink using ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a web application with a HTML Action link. My requirement is to have a mouse hover / Tool tip to the action link where the details of corresponding HTML Action links has to be displayed when mouse is placed over the link.

Following is the HTML Action link

```
 <td> @Html.ActionLink(@item.Split('.')[0], "myMethod", new { name = item }, new { Class = "action add", title ="My Tooltip"})</td>
```

I want to call a method from here that returns the corresponding details and the details has to be shown as a tool tip to the users.

Help me in resolving this issue.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the JQuery plugin to do a Tooltip.  It will attach to the control's `title` attribute as you would like.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );
  </script>
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmOaKJ

For the dynamic piece and with the assumption your model has a `Title` property, you should be able to handle it like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.Split('.')[0], "myMethod", new { name = item }, new { @class = "action add", @title = item.Title})
```

Comment: Thanks!! But my requirement is to have dynamic values assigned to the title attribute instead of hard coding. I would like to call a method that will return a string dynamically and assign to the title attribute.Is that possible?